# Entity Framework 6.0 Code first - getting duplicated items in a simple query when filtering by primary key

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

In my project we are using the EF Code First (v.6.0.0.0) and the MS SQL Server 2012.

I've updated to the Entity Framework to the 6th version.
The strange thing that at some point after the update I started getting duplicated items while filtering records by the primary key.

First of all I started to get the 'Sequence contains more than one element' exception in the following code

```
var cateringService = context.CateringServices
                             .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == query.CateringServiceId)
```

I've checked the database and the parameter - the `Id` is a **primary key**, it is marked as **unique**, and the parameter was valid. As the `Id` was set as primary key in the mapping:

```
this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
```

I've replaces the call with the `FirstOrDefault` and code worked well.
I've tried to retrieve all the items that are mathing the predicate using the following code:

```
var cateringServices = context.CateringServices
                              .Where(x => x.Id == query.CateringServiceId)
                              .ToList();
```

It seemed that I'm getting the 13 instances of the 'CateringService' entity referencing the same row. Please look at the screenshots attached:

[image]
[image]

As well I've started to get the `A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred: An EntityReference can have no more than one related object, but the query returned more than one related object.` exception while accessing the CateringService entities via entity reference. We are using the lazy approach and lazy loading is enabled.

When trying to access the 'CateringService' using the `Include("CateringService")` everythings works well, but we can not just replace all the `SingleOrDefault` calls and remove all the lazy loading usages from the project at this point.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for being not quite clear.
There is a single record in the database that matches the condition. 
The `Id` column is set as the Primary Key so it is unique.

**UPDATE 2**

Below is the code from the migration generated by EF based on fluent mappings.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.CateringServices",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 200),
                    CreatedDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    CultureString = c.String(maxLength: 10),
                    AddressId = c.Int(),
                    CateringServiceGroupId = c.Int(),
                    ContactInformationId = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Addresses", t => t.AddressId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.CateringServiceGroups", t => t.CateringServiceGroupId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ContactInformation", t => t.ContactInformationId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AddressId)
            .Index(t => t.CateringServiceGroupId)
            .Index(t => t.ContactInformationId);
```

Comment: What's the definition of `query` in your code? (`x.Id == query.CateringServiceId`)

Comment: It is instance of a really simple class - having just one property `public Int32 CateringServiceId { get; set; }`

Comment: but I've tried using the hard-coded value, e.g. `x => x.Id == 1`. or any other existing id in the database. still getting the same result.

Comment: Have you checked the related tables (`Addresses`, `CateringServiceGroups` and `ContactInformation`) to see if they contain duplicate records?

Comment: yes, they don't but it seems that the problem was in a different entity mapping in the following lines: `this.HasOptional(x => x.CateringService).WithOptionalDependent().Map(x => x.MapKey("CateringServiceId"));`. for some reason when querying the `CateringServices` table there was an left outer join performed.

Comment: Could you please check the SQL query generated by Entity Framework and may be there will be a clue to what is wrong? Based on your description I think there is more than one relation between `CateringServices` and other entities and this causes duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `SingleOrDefault`.because  your screen short have the  same value for Id cloumn.So you need want to this .

else you need must check id is a primary key. and **check set is identity yes for your Id column**

because

**FirstOrDefault()**

is for when zero or more results are expected to be present in the input collection and the call returns the first item if there are multiple results, Default if none.

**SingleOrDefault()**

is for when zero or one result is expected in the input collection and the call returns the one result if exactly one result is present, Default **if no results and exception if more than one result**.

and refer this  [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

**Updated:**

Since you reverse-engineered the database when the Id column was not set as IDENTITY yet, the code first model has been generated with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` set for the Id property on the entity.

That causes EF to create an insert statement with the Id set, which no longer works after changing the column to *IDENTITY*.

You have to manually fix that configuration, by either setting it to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` or just removing it altogether, since that is the default value for integer fields.

You need to change

```
this.HasKey(e => e.Id);
   Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

More deatisls

[EF Code First 5.0.rc Migrations doesn`t update Identity property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777669/ef-code-first-5-0-rc-migrations-doesnt-update-identity-property)

[Entity Framework 5 code-first not creating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601459/entity-framework-5-code-first-not-creating-database)

> Edit : Please deleted your old table values and re generate it or remove same primary key rows. You should need to regenerate your `CateringServices`  table values :), if the problems not cleared yet.

Comment: Right. But if you've read the title of the question you could have noticed that this is not quite the case where the FirstOrDefault should have been used.

But the problem is that there should be a single record. As it is in the database. 

And anyway your answer does not solve the issue with the 'A relationship multiplicity constraint violation occurred' error.

Comment: Yup, But your screen short have the  same value for Id cloumn.So you need want to this

Comment: Right. That is what I'm asking about. I've stated that the ID was unique in the database.

Comment: "I've checked the database and the parameter - the Id is a primary key, it is unique, and the parameter was valid."

Comment: read one more time in my answer. have you set IsIdentity=true in your Id coulumn?

Comment: Can you show your primary key setting? and Is Identity setings?

Comment: I did. I'm using the EF Code First and Fluent Mappings. That is the code responsible for that - this.HasKey(x => x.Id);

Comment: I think the isidentity is not set, So you got the problem.Please make sure the is  identity is set :http://www.google.co.in/imgres?sa=X&biw=1024&bih=666&tbm=isch&tbnid=9I8Owmy37WV6nM:&imgrefurl=https://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2009/09/15/inserting-master-detail-data-into-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database.aspx&docid=HVN6riU4ED5T-M&imgurl=http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/bethmassi/WindowsLiveWriter/InsertingMasterDetailDataintoaSQLServerC_C610/image_6.png&w=713&h=582&ei=DQCqUvaEDMnprAe-poHgCw&zoom=1&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=168&tbnw=206&start=0&ndsp=13&ved=1t:429,r:7,s:0&tx=878&ty=425

Comment: I may add the fluent mapping as well, but it will make the question too hard to read.

Comment: I have Edit my answer .please check it

Comment: I have update the solution, please take a look at now :)

Comment: We did not reverse engineered the database. The project was using the EF Code First from the beginning. We've started to experience the issue just after the update to the 6th version.

However your solution worked ))

Comment: sorry for unmarking question and thanks for the effort. however the project appeared again. it seems like there is another reason in that.

Comment: @danyloid - I think your database have old values with same primary key value, So you got the error, clear the table and one more try

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Top(1) instead of .FirstOrDefault() or .SingleOrDefault().

I am new for Linq but as i know top() will return only specified no of rows.I don't know about FirstOrDefault and SingleOrDefault.

Comment: Actually you should use FirstOrDefault, otherwise top(1) still returns an IEnumberable.  

FirstOrDefault() will return the first item in the sequence if there are _any_ or will return null  
SingleOrDefault will return null if there are none, the item if there is one (and only one) and throw an exception if there are multiple items